# Get HTML Content Upon Submit

Tags: html, jsp

In Jsp while i press submit button instead of passing values to action.
   I want the HTML content of that form with all values it is possible??

If possible give an example. Let me know if any clarification is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isnt clear where do you need this html content?

If on browser, use an alert in an onSubmit event -

```
alert(document.myForm.innerHTML);
```

To get this on to server side, you will need to pass this content as part of form submission, maybe in a hidden field.

```
in onSubmit() event:
myForm.myHiddenHtmlContent = myForm.innerHTML;
```

For InnerHTML **with** current form values:
Its not plain easy, check out the following link - 
[innerHTML with current form values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826222/innerhtml-with-current-form-values)
This uses jquery, but you can also write your own without it as well.

Including an example - 
Ok, it looks like it works in IE but not in FireFox. Basically you need to `setAttribute('value')` for each form element to make it work.

Use following -

```
var formElements = document.getElementById("myFormId").elements;
for (var x = 0; x <= formElements.length - 1; x++)
{
    if (formElements[x].value) {
        formElements[x].setAttribute("value", formElements[x].value);
    }
}

//Now you are ready to call innerHTML
myForm.myHiddenHtmlContent = myForm.innerHTML;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: you are right,In above point no 2 server side as you mentioned  but one thing while onsubmit i pass this server i am not able to get the updated value for ex in textbox at first value is 10 and after updated to 20 and submit but it still remains as 10 ..dear sir let me know any clarification.

Comment: Now you are referring to innerHTML **with** current form values? Well that is little complicated, checkout my update.

Comment: Thanks d-live in js it is possible any example is highly  appreciated