# Convert DOM to HTML via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Okay so I already know I can get the entire HTML document's markup (minus the DOCTYPE) using:

```
document.documentElement.outerHTML
```

however that will only get me the original source markup, and not the current state of the DOM, which is really what I am looking for. For my immediate needs I really just want to preserve the state of a form within the document (think of it in terms of an an auto-save).

- Please note this is not being used in a standard website/webapp format, so posting, submitting, etc. really isn't an option. I need a pure JavaScript way to acquire an HTML string representation of the current DOM tree, so an external caller can save it to disk for later use.

Now I know I can manually iterate through all the form elements, grabbing each and every value, and doing a string replacement on the result of the above outerHTML (via regular expressions), to build an HTML string that mirrors the current DOM, but I was hoping there was an easier way to do this (maybe something built in). Like a DOM to HTML parser/writer.

However so far I have not found a built in way to do this. Just wanted to reach out and see if anyone else has needed to do this. And ask if my above proposed method the best way to approach this particular problem, before I begin implementing it.

Comment: Afaik, you're mistaken, calling `outerHTML` or `innerHTML` does indeed get you the markup **as is** at the time it's called, not the original source. It does however not get you the properties, which you shouldn't really need to get that way anyway.

Comment: `[...]however that will only get me the original source markup, and not the current state of the DOM[...]`  this is not true, `outerHTML` will return the current source markup. Your problem is that the current values, that are holde by the form elements are stored as property in the html element and not as attribute. And only the attribute is part of the html code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [innerHTML with current form values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826222/innerhtml-with-current-form-values)

Comment: Okay, so yes I am mistaken (it just appeared that way in the sample I was working with). So I should be able to use JS to update the DOM, adding the appropriate value attribute where necessary (based on the value property), and then use outerHTML to get the document as a string. Let me give that a shot.

Comment: The main point here being, there shouldn't be any reason to store the entire HTML of a page to remember some state. Serialize the form to a useful format, for instance an object, instead.

Comment: @Xorcist No, the `value` property will not update the `value` attribute in the HTML. You need to use `setAttribute('value', newValue)` to update the attribute. The same thing goes for the `checked` property.

Comment: Without over complicating things, I'm using a WKWebView within iOS to render and persist dynamically generated forms in an entirely offline setting. The html files are generated outside the app, added to the app while online, then accessed offline on the device due to wireless restrictions in the field. Each html file is a unique instance of a form (each one individually keyed), so I see no need to add further complexity, when really I just want to update the local html file directly, so the user doesn't lose everything when opening, closing, and re-opening the form.

Comment: And yes, updating the "value" attribute based on the "value" property gave me the exact functionality I needed. Thank you for all the help, this was very insightful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample HTML page in which I tried the supplied function:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">

      function getFormState() {
        // this could be set outside this function if calling multiple times
        var theForm = document.forms[0];
        console.log(theForm);
        
        var theData = new FormData(theForm);
        console.log(theData);
        
        // get the state of the form as an iterator of key/value pairs
        var state = theData.entries();
        console.log(state);
        
        // convert the iterator into an array of key/value pairs
        var stateArray = Array.from(state);
        console.log(stateArray);
        
        // Use JSON.stringify to change the key/value pair array state into a string
        var stateString = JSON.stringify(stateArray);
        console.log(stateString);
        
        return stateString;
      }
         
    </script>
    <style>

      #header {
          background: #ffffff;
          position: fixed;
          width: 100%;
          height: 30px;
          padding: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
          top: 0;
          z-index: 1;
      }
      
      #content{ 
          margin-top: 40px;
      }

      body, input, select, textarea  {
        font-family: monospace;
        font-size: 10pt;
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      td {
        padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
      }

      input:not([type="button"]):not([type="checkbox"]):not([type="color"]):not([type="file"]):not([type="image"]):not([type="radio"]):not([type="range"]):not([type="reset"]):not([type="submit"]), select, textarea {
        -webkit-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
        outline: none;
        padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
        margin: 5px 1px 3px 0px;
        border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
      }

      input:not([type="button"]):not([type="checkbox"]):not([type="color"]):not([type="file"]):not([type="image"]):not([type="radio"]):not([type="range"]):not([type="reset"]):not([type="submit"]):focus, select:focus, textarea:focus {
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
        padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
        margin: 5px 1px 3px 0px;
        border: 1px solid rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
      }
      
    </style>
    <title>HTML5 FormData Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="frmForm">
      <div id="header">
        <button type="button" onclick="getFormState()">getFormState</button>
        <hr>
      </div>
      <div id="content">
        <table border="1">
          <tr>
            <td>Button</td>
            <td><input id="btnButton" type="button" value="Button"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Checkbox</td>
            <td><input id="chkCheckbox" type="checkbox"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Color</td>
            <td><input id="clrColor" type="color" value="#000000"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Datalist</td>
            <td>
              <input id="txtDatalist" type="text" list="choices" value="">
              <datalist id="choices">
                <option value="One"></option>
                <option value="Two"></option>
                <option value="Three"></option>
              </datalist>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Date</td>
            <td><input id="calDate" type="date" value=""></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Datetime (Deprecated)</td>
            <td><input id="calDateTime" type="datetime" value=""></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Datetime (Local)</td>
            <td><input id="calDateTimeLocal" type="datetime-local" value=""></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Disabled</td>
            <td><input id="txtDisabled" type="text" value="Disabled" disabled=""></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>E-Mail</td>
            <td><input id="txtEMail" type="email" value=""></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>File</td>
            <td><input id="binFile" type="file" value=""></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Hidden</td>
            <td><input id="txtHidden" type="hidden" value="HIDDEN"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Image (Submit)</td>
            <td><input id="btnImage" type="image" src="data:image/png;base64,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"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Month</td>
            <td><input id="calMonth" type="month" value=""></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td><input id="numNumber" type="number" min="0" max="10" step="1" required="" value=""></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td><input id="txtPassword" type="password" value=""></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Radio</td>
            <td>
              <input id="radRadio1" type="radio" name="radRadio" value="1">One<br>
              <input id="radRadio2" type="radio" name="radRadio" value="2">Two<br>
              <input id="radRadio3" type="radio" name="radRadio" value="3">Three
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Range</td>
            <td><input id="numRange" type="range" min="0" max="10" value="5"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Readonly</td>
            <td><input id="txtReadonly" type="text" value="Readonly" readonly=""></td>
          </tr>          
          <tr>
            <td>Reset</td>
            <td><input id="btnReset" type="reset"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Search</td>
            <td><input id="txtSearch" type="search" placeholder="search text" value=""></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Select</td>
            <td>
              <select id="sltSelect">
                <option value="" disabled="" selected="">&lt;Select&gt;</option>
                <option value="1">One</option>
                <option value="2">Two</option>
                <option value="3">Three</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Select (Multiple)</td>
            <td>
              <select id="sltMultiSelect" multiple="">
                <option value="1">One</option>
                <option value="2">Two</option>
                <option value="3">Three</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Submit</td>
            <td><input id="btnSubmit" type="submit"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Telephone</td>
            <td><input id="txtTelephone" type="tel" value=""></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Textbox</td>
            <td><input id="txtTextbox" type="text" value=""></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Textarea</td>
            <td><textarea id="txtTextarea"></textarea></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Time</td>
            <td><input id="calTime" type="time" value=""></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>URL</td>
            <td><input id="txtURL" type="url" value=""></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Week</td>
            <td><input id="calWeek" type="week" value=""></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

which returns the following:

[image: Output]

I am able to manually iterate over all the inputs to get what I need, in fact that is my current solution, but the FormData solution seemed like a much cleaner approach, it's just not returning the expected data.

In fact the only input that ever seems to populate is the RadioButton.

Comment: Ahhhh... it's because the input elements don't have names! This HTML doc is being used with interop language in a native application's web view (so I didn't need the names, as they never needed to be submitted). FormData does appear to work as long as the name attributes are present.